# Filter a String which holds a TimeStamp - Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, filter, substring

I have written a function which generate a `TimeStamp` and convert it to a `String` using `toString()`. I want to `remove` the `whitespaces` and other `special character` from that string. Is there is any efficient way to do it ?

This is a function which generate `ID` using `TimeStamp` , since timestamp will be unique (`Note :` When IDs are generated at different M.Sec)

```
fun autoGenerateID() : String = Timestamp(java.util.Date().getTime()).toString()
```

When I call the function, It should return :
`20190612121912463`

But the produced result was :
`2019-06-12 12:19:12.463`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest dropping the use of Timestamp class. it is outdated and anything it provides can be achieved in easier ways.

For your use case you could just use the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). It would look like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS").format(Date())
```